# SPSS format a CTABLE with repeated row lables

Tags: spss

Say I have a table which hass gender and age counts, in CTABLE I would like to repeat the labels on each row, ie rather than:

```
Male   | Aged 0 to 15
       | Aged 16 to 59
       | Aged 60 and older
Female | Aged 0 to 15
       | Aged 16 to 59
       | Aged 60 and older
```

I would like:

```
Male   | Aged 0 to 15
Male   | Aged 16 to 59
Male   | Aged 60 and older
Female | Aged 0 to 15
Female | Aged 16 to 59
Female | Aged 60 and older
```

In reality I have four levels:

```
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | White | Born UK
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | White | Born Outside UK
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | Mixed | Born UK
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | Mixed | Born Outside UK
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | Asian | Born UK
Male | Aged 0 to 15 | Asian | Born Outside UK
```

etc.

Thanks.

Added by me:

Here is the syntax for the table where I would like the repeated row labels. The table contains just counts in columns of how many people with this combination live in one of 12 regions.

```
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=sex age5 eth cob region DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE sex [C] > age5 [C] > eth [C] > cob [C][COUNT F40.0] BY region [C]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=sex eth cob region ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE MISSING=EXCLUDE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=age5 ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
```

Comment: What statistics are you trying to present in the resulting tables? If counts only then a simple solution exist however this same solution shall not work with certain percentage calculations.

Comment: {CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=sex age5 hhtype hnresdnt region DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE sex [C] > age5 [C] > hhtype [C] > hnresdnt [C][COUNT F40.0] BY region [C]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=sex hhtype hnresdnt region ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE MISSING=EXCLUDE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=age5 ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
}

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural/direct way to achieve what you are trying to do here. Nonetheless I provide a couple of solutions, which I have used myself in the past, that you may want to consider both with their own drawbacks. Alternatively you may want to consider using AGGREGATE or VBA to post edit the table after exporting to Excel (if it is destined to be directed to Excel).

```
GET FILE="C:\PROGRAM FILES\IBM\SPSS\STATISTICS\23\SAMPLES\ENGLISH\EMPLOYEE DATA.SAV".

/* Original Table */.
CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES= gender jobcat DISPLAY=NONE 
    /TABLE gender > jobcat[COUNT COLPCT ROWPCT]
      /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gender jobcat EMPTY=EXCLUDE.

/* Solution 1: Dirty hack, insert granular level variable far left. Force repeat row labels however generate redundant column in output table */.
CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES= gender jobcat DISPLAY=NONE 
    /TABLE gender > jobcat [COUNT COLPCT ROWPCT]
      /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gender jobcat EMPTY=EXCLUDE.



/* Solution 2: Create a single new variable with all combination of categories but again this may not help you derive the correct percentage scores */.
COMPUTE GenJob=sum((Gender="m")*10, JobCat).
VALUE LABELS GenJob
 1 "Female - Clerical"
 2 "Female - Custodial"
 3 "Male - Manager"
 11 "Male - Clerical"
 12 "Male - Custodial"
 13 "Male - Manager".

CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES= GenJob DISPLAY=NONE 
    /TABLE GenJob [COUNT COLPCT ROWPCT]
      /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=GenJob EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
```